# Relate a project to a local maven project

Tags: maven

I've downloaded locally an open source maven project (P). I made some changes on this project and I packaged it using mvn package which produces a single jar file.

My main project (P) depend on (P1). How can I relates the two project so if I re-package (P1) changes takes affect on main project (P) without re-assigning generated jar file (because with every packaging a new jar file with different name is generated).

How can I also bind P1 source code to P in order to edit it (when I attached source code to generated jar file, eclipse do not allow me to change it) ?

Answer (score 0):

1: Make a project `Q` which will be a parent to both `P1` and `P`.
2: Add a `-SNAPSHOT` suffix to the version of your project `P1`, e.g. `<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` - this will let maven know that it should always rebuild the dependency, instead of using the one installed in your local repo.
3: When declaring project `P1` as a dependency of `P`, use the version declared in the previous step, e.g.

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>P1</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

4: Build your projects by running `mvn clean install` from the root directory of project `Q`.